# CSS3 Animates in all but IE (10+)

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

EDIT: Problem was solved by using 1 instead of 100 in @keyframes.

I'm using some basic jQuery to keep everything on my site as a single .html doc.  Doing so, I have 6 pages that are overlaid on each other, and I bring up the one a user clicks on via z-index.

I'm using the animations to fade out the old page and fade in the one clicked.

Here is my .visible class, .invisible is the same just with fadeout and a 1s duration.  I expanded this class for legibility.

```
.visible{
    -webkit-animation:fadein;
    -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
    -webkit-animation-direction:normal;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -moz-animation:fadein;
    -moz-animation-duration:2s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:ease;
    -moz-animation-delay:0s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:1;
    -moz-animation-direction:normal;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -o-animation:fadein;
    -o-animation-duration:2s;
    -o-animation-timing-function:ease;
    -o-animation-delay:0s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count:1;
    -o-animation-direction:normal;
    -o-animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    animation:fadein;
    animation-duration:2s;
    animation-timing-function:ease;
    animation-delay:0s;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    animation-direction:normal;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

Currently, this is working as planned across the latest Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera.

On IE11, however, the animation is not slowly changing the opacity.  Instead, the page the user clicked on loads in without fade instantly (so the old and new page are on the screen at the same time), then a second or so later the old page disappears (instantly, without fade).

IE10+ supports CSS3, so I'm a bit confused as to what I'm doing wrong with it.  Firefox and IE use the same bit of code, and Firefox is working fine.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is my @keyframes rules as requested:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:100;
    }
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your `@keyframes` at-rule.

Comment: Opacity in your `to` should be 1, not 100.

Comment: @Oriol added the keyframes!

Comment: @JosiahKeller,  That was it!  Thanks!  Silly mistake on my part...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opacity is supposed to be between 0 and 1, with 1 being full opacity.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Can't believe I didn't catch that.

Comment: I work on the Internet Explorer team. Technically the browser is supposed to *clamp* the value if it is outside the range of 0 to 1. Internet Explorer appears to clamp the value, but then proceeds to prevent the animation. I'll check to see if we have a bug on this already, and submit one if we do not.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Awesome, I didn't know that.  I assumed the other browsers were just being lax.  Thanks.